# IE8 - button background Image not showing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a submit button which has the following CSS:

```
  .button{
    border:1px solid #015691;
    background-image:url('http://boundsblazer.com/pkg/pics/
         buttons/small-button.png');
    color:#ffffff;
    height:18px;
    font-size:8pt;
    font-family:sans-serif, verdana;
    cursor:pointer;
    line-height:14px;
    margin-bottom:-5px;
    border-bottom-color:#222222;

    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    behavior: url("http://boundsblazer.com/pkg/plugins/PIE.htc");
  }
```

and my JQuery...

```
$(".button").mousedown(function(){
    $(this).css('border-bottom-width', '0px');
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(\'http://boundsblazer.com/pkg/pics/buttons/small-button-pressed.png\')');

    $(this).mouseout(function(){
          $(this).css('border-bottom-width', '1px');
          $(this).css('background-image', 'url(\'http://boundsblazer.com/pkg/pics/buttons/small-button.png\')');
    });
    $(this).mouseup(function(){
          $(this).css('border-bottom-width', '1px');
          $(this).css('background-image', 'url(\'http://boundsblazer.com/pkg/pics/buttons/small-button.png\')');
    });
});
```

Strangely, this has no problems in IE7 or IE9, just IE8. What happens is that the image for the buttons doesn't show. It works on Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE7, and IE9, just not IE8. If you want to see it, its [http://boundsblazer.com](http://boundsblazer.com/). Please help!

On a side note, the "border solution" doesn't work, as you can see I declared the border in the CSS.

**Issue solved:**

The `behavior` tag doesn't work in IE8, so if you want PIE CSS3 for rounded borders in IE8, its a no-go. Also, adding:

`background:transparent url()`

and getting rid of:

`background-image:url()`

worked.

Comment: The argument to `url()` does not require single quotes. Did you try `$(this).css("background-image", "url(http://boundsblazer.com/pkg/pics/buttons/small-button-pressed.png)");`?

Comment: That didn't change anything... :(

Comment: Could it be that the behavior in .button changes the background to something IE8 doesn't understand?

Comment: Maybe, ill cut that for a sec.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue! But how else will I implement rounded borders? D:

Comment: Also, you can make that an answer, and I'll accept it. :3

Comment: In my case, only removing the `behavior` property from the CSS solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, change:

```
background-image:url('http://boundsblazer.com/pkg/pics/buttons/small-button.png');
```

to:

```
background:transparent url('http://boundsblazer.com/pkg/pics/buttons/small-button.png');
```

You'll also need to change the jquery.

[Load this in IE8](http://jsfiddle.net/sKLAL/)

Al

Comment: Im not sure im the exact problem is documented, but where possible, when you're first declaring the background, always use `background:` you can then be more specific in later css and use `background-image:`